# SendInput function on a virtual keyboard

Tags: c++, winapi, mouse, sendinput

I am relatively new to c++, and recently, I have been trying to get a simulated mouse click program to work on the on screen keyboard present in Windows 10. To do this, I tried to use SendInput, but it does not seem to do anything on the virtual keyboard.

```
INPUT input;
input.type = INPUT_MOUSE;
input.mi.dwFlags = MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN;
SendInput(1, &input, sizeof(INPUT));

input.type = INPUT_MOUSE;
input.mi.dwFlags = MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP;
SendInput(1, &input, sizeof(INPUT));
```

When the program is run, the mouse clicks are simulated elsewhere, but the program does not work on the virtual keyboard. Is there any way to produce input at a near hardware level, so that the program can click on the virtual keyboard? Or is this not possible?

Edit: Running the program as administrator worked. However, I am still wondering, is SendInput the closest one can get to simulating hardware mouse clicks?

Comment: Why do you want to simulate mouse input for a virtual keyboard so that it can simulate keyboard input? Why not, you know, just simulate the keyboard input directly?

Comment: Could you provide a minimum compilable code?

Comment: Try running your application as Administrator.  [UIPI](http://securityinternals.blogspot.com/2014/01/user-interface-privilege-isolation.html) is probably getting in the way (because OSK runs as a privileged app).

Comment: @PaulSanders Thanks, running the application as administrator worked. However, I am still wondering, is SendInput is the closest one can get to hardware level?

Comment: @Quacko From user application level, no other WINAPI are official suggested to use.